# Swift pattern matching with protocol

Tags: swift, pattern-matching, protocols

Don't know if it's a bug in compiler or there's something that I'n not aware of.

When matching against concrete types I can combine two cases like:

```
    enum SomeEnum {
        case a, b, c
    }

    let param: (SomeEnum, Any) = something
    switch (param) {
        case (.a, let param as Int),
             (.b, let param as Int):
            print("a or b with solid type (Int) \(param)")
        default: print("none of above")
    }
```

However, if I would like to match against protocol like:

```
    switch (param) {
        case (.a, let param as Equatable),
             (.b, let param as Equatable):
            print("a or b with protocol \(param)")
        default: print("none of above")
    }
```

I get `Segmentation fault: 11` during compilation. Solution for this is to duplicate code like:

```
    switch (param) {
        case (.a, let param as Equatable):
            print("a or b with protocol \(param)")
         case (.b, let param as Equatable):
            print("a or b with protocol \(param)")
        default: print("none of above")
    }
```

Can someone tell me why it behaves like this?

Comment: A crashing compiler is *always* a bug.

Comment: A segfault is _always_ a compiler bug. https://bugs.swift.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa or https://bugreport.apple.com/ For fun, you can also contribute to https://github.com/practicalswift/swift-compiler-crashes

Comment: As a slightly better workaround, you can use `fallthrough` in the first case.

Comment: Really neither of the last two examples should compile as you cannot cast to `Equatable` because it's a protocol with `Self` requirements. In the latest Swift 4 snapshot, both yield the compiler error "*Protocol 'Equatable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements*" as expected – so looks like the seg fault has already been fixed.

Comment: ^ Actually scratch that – when attempting to cast to a protocol without associated types or `Self` requirements, I get an abort trap in the latest Swift 4 snapshot, so still go ahead and file that bug.

Comment: The compiler crashes even for `case (.a, let param), (.b, let param):`, *without* casting to a protocol – but only if the type of the second tuple member is `Any`.

Answer (score 0):

Messed around with this a bit.

I'm pretty sure `param` cast to equatable is pretty much useless and can't be used in any way. I'm surprised it works at all, given that it requires `Self` and doesn't work when cast to a normal variable.

I'm guessing the compiler shouldn't be able to do *either* of these, but your second example works either accidentally, or as a remnant of an older approach. (as a side note, the Switch pattern matching is due for an overhaul so this might produce a proper compiler error soon.).

I'm thinking the reason the first one doesn't work has something to do with the way variables are defined when using multiple-option switch case variables (that's a mouth full). If it were trying to set two different instances of `Equatable` to the same variable, the underlying Type could be two different Types, which it shouldn't even be able to try, but if it tries, as it is here, it breaks something internally.

My guess is this has already been reported or fixed for Swift 4, but it wouldn't hurt to file a radar and/or report on the [Swift bug tracker](https://bugs.swift.org/):